# Deleted question by called2voyage

Tags: discussion

: I see you blocked the question about feasibility of an Space Shuttle in reinforced concrete, please review my question, as I've added references to everything; if you need some references more in an specific issue of the question, please let me know. 
This question was forwarded from the Aviation Stack Exchange, where I do have privileges large enough to unblock questions, I'm new in the Space section.

I ignore about Stack Exchange policies regarding transfer of privileges and reputation between different topics, but please reconsider the blockade also under this light.
I can't send right now a reference in English for the effects of fire on concrete, but Google translate will do the task of translating the document in Spanish well enough. Thanks, have a good season, regards. Salut +

Comment: If you want the question to be re-opened you should mark it as such rather than writing a post like this one.

Comment: Urquiola, your question has not been deleted or closed. Rather, it is your answer that has been deleted. The main issue with your answer is that it has not demonstrated that the Space Shuttle could be built in concrete, which is your question. Rather you seem to make a few assumptions which you believe might be borne out in tests. This is not how we prepare answers here.

Comment: Thanks. Adding technical info by an answer to my own question helps in answering the original question about Concrete SpaceShip building, if I knew how to do the calculations, I'd have do it myself and won't need asking anyone. Adding info, that you never know who will benefit from, helps readers. Unless you have memory storage or page space shortness problems. I can't imagine a reason for blocking a question, the term was this 'blockage', rather than deleting an answer. I can't find the box for requesting a re-opening, if you can, and think it's good, please do it. Salut +